# Hide Ajax Div and Show Loader Div until data is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to display a loader div until the div that gets populated by the Ajax is returned. So I want to hide one Div "responseDiv" until it gets populated by the Ajax data, In the meantime I want to display a loader div.
My CSS

```
#loading {
    background: url('images/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    /*top: 0%;
    left : 0%;*/
    background-color : #ffffff ;
}

#responseDivOverlay {
position: absolute; 
background-color : #ffffff ;
display: block;
opacity: 0.7;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;  
}
```

My Two Divs

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="responseDiv">
```

My JavaScript

I'm trying to display the loader until the getMessage has populated the data in the response div.

```
<!-- Slider Code-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(function () {
              $("#slider-range").slider({
                  range: true,
                  min: <%=lowestPrice%>,
                  max: <%=highPrice%>,
                  step: 0.01,
                  values: [<%=lowestPrice%>, <%=highPrice%>],
                  stop: function (event, ui) {
                      //alert(ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);

                      // HERE, WHAT I HAVE BEEN TRYING SO FAR

                      //setTimeout(function() {
                      //     document.getElementById("responseDiv").style.display='hide';
                      //}, 1000);

                      getMessage("1", ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);

                  },
                  slide: function (event, ui) {
                      $("#amount").val("£" + parseFloat(Math.round(ui.values[0] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + " - £" + parseFloat(Math.round(ui.values[1] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
                      //$("#amount").val("£" + ui.values[0] + " - £" + ui.values[1]);
                      //parseFloat(Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                  }

              });
              $("#amount").val("£" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
          " - £" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

          });
      </script>
```

Comment: All this: `try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
   catch (e) {
   try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
   catch (e) {
   try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
   catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; } 
   }` can simply be replaced with this: `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`. All browsers have supported a native XHR for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you hide the 'responseDiv' using css (display: none) and change it's state using jQuery once the ajax finished loading?

Comment: How do I change its state using jQuery? And how do I know exactly when the Ajax has finished loading?

Comment: Read about sending Ajax request and then you'll figure out how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

you can change visibility of a div using css selectors.
to hide:
$("#MyDivId").display = none;
to display:
$("#MyDivId").display = block;

Comment: Then you can simple do `$("#MyDivId").show()` and `$("#MyDivId").hide()`